# How to set Froala editor default text?

Tags: php, html, froala

I write that in my code:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" value="something"></textarea>
```

I want it to be this way:

[image]

but I see this instead:

[image]

How can I change it?

Comment: Where is the javascript code to init froala ?

Comment: $(function () {
            $('textarea#content').froalaEditor()
        });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the text like this:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" value="something">something</textarea>
```

or you can do this with placeholder:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" value="something" placeholder="something"></textarea>
```

hope it helped you

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" ></textarea>

  $(function() {
    $('#content').froalaEditor({
      placeholderText: 'Start typing something...'
    })
  });
```

Comment: Not sure why that last answer was downvoted becuase it's the correct way to use Froala to set placeholder text.

Comment: That's true, but I think the OP wanted to set a default starting value rather than the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

#### React

The way to set default content (aka a textarea's `defaultValue`) in Froala WYSIWYG React is to use the prop `model`.

```
<FroalaEditor
  model="<div>HTML String</div>"
  onModelChange={handleModelChange}
/>
```

Ref: https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg